# Can I tell my php function to not execute until the "file_get_contents" has loaded the page using javascript in php code?

Tags: javascript, php, return, delay, file-get-contents

This is my php function:

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/index.php'); 
$regex = '/<img class="pic" src="(.*?)">/';   
preg_match($regex, $result, $matches);
 return($matches[1]);
```

it's a function to get a picture from that link, sometimes it return the picture, sometimes not, because the image in the site sometimes take seconde to load sometimes not.
I want to prevent that from happening in my function, I want to delay the return until the image is loaded, i know this is not possible with php, sleep() didn't help, so I know that I must do it with javascript, but I don't know how to do it, please help ty!

Comment: If you fetch a page using file_get_contents(), you will only get the HTML document. It won't load external assets (like images, css, js) or execute any javascript on the page.

Comment: Okey is there any other commande for that please

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to load something asynchronously, I guess the simplest solution would be to launch another request from the client side, e.g.:

1. Load the page without the desired picture
2. Create a new script, that would be fetching that image URL on the server. Let's call in `fetch-image.php` for example.
3. Make sure your script will render the image and return correct `Content-Type` header. Samples [can be found here](https://www.lifewire.com/file-extensions-and-mime-types-3469109). For that your code will need modification, please see below.
4. Move your code, mentioned above to the new script
5. Replace the image `src="/fetch-image.php"` attribute with the path to the fetch script

Modified script:

```php
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/index.php'); 
$regex = '/<img class="pic" src="(.*?)">/';   
preg_match($regex, $result, $matches);
echo file_get_contents($matches[1]);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping, it's bit hard to do but i'll try